# Dynamic constant assignment error in Ruby implementation of merge sort algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, mergesort

Following is my code of implementing merge sort algo in ruby.After running it i am getting the following error.Please help me in resolving the dynamic constant error.

Error which I am getting at terminal is:

```
ruby merge.rb
merge.rb:8: dynamic constant assignment
 Li=Array.new(n1.object_id)
    ^
 merge.rb:9: dynamic constant assignment
 Ri=Array.new(n2.object_id)
        ^
```

My code:

```
def merge(list,l,m,r)
  i
  j
  k
  n1 = m - l + 1
  n2 =  r - m

Li=Array.new(n1)
Ri=Array.new(n2)

0.upto(n1-1)do |i|
    Li[i] = list[l + i]
end
0.upto(n2-1)do |j|
    Ri[j] = list[m + 1+ j]
end

i = 0
j = 0
k = l
while i < n1 && j < n2
  if Li[i] <= Ri[j]
     list[k] = Li[i]
     i=i+1
  else
    list[k] = Ri[j]
    j=j+1
  end
  k=k+1
end

while i < n1
   list[k] = Li[i]
   i=i+1
   k=k+1
end

  while j < n2
   list[k] = Ri[j]
   j=j+1
   k=k+1
  end
end

def mergeSort(list,l,r)
  if (l < r)
    m = l+(r-l)/2
    mergeSort(list, l, m)
    mergeSort(list, m+1, r)
    merge(list, l, m, r)
  end
end

def printArray(list, size)
  0.upto(size-1) do |i|
     puts list[i]
  end
end

list = Array[12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
puts "Given array is"
printArray(list,list.size)

mergeSort(list, 0, list.size - 1)

puts "Sorted array is"
printArray(list,list.size)
```

Comment: You don't really need to show the rest of the code, as it has no influence on the error. You can demonstrate that by writing your method with just the problem lines. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - prefer minimal examples on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Li=Array.new(n1)
Ri=Array.new(n2)
```

Names starts with an uppercase letter are constants. The error is telling you that you are trying to modify a constant. Change the name `Li` and `Ri` so that they start with lowercase letter.